# Java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java

I am getting the below error  sporadically in my J2EE container. That is some time the container is getting up , without any problem , and some time the container is not coming up ,because of this error , have any one seen this error before...? what may be the cause ..? does it involves any  class loader/security problem ..?

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/rsa/authagent/authapi/realmstat/AUTHav, method: a signature: (Lcom/rsa/authagent/authapi/authmsg/AUTHa0;)V) catch_type not a subclass of Throwable
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2259)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1852)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1582)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:52)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:408)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:400)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:297)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:531)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1552)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1466)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1699)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1634)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1299)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
        at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.realmstat.AUTHi.j(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.realmstat.AUTHi.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.realmstat.AUTHh.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.realmstat.AUTHg.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthSessionFactory.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthSessionFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthSessionFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at netx.esf.authentication.rsa.service.RsaAuthenticationServiceImpl.instantiateRsaAPI(RsaAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1050)
        at netx.esf.authentication.rsa.service.RsaAuthenticationServiceImpl.start(RsaAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at arch.service.beans.RepBasedServiceBean.onMessage(RepBasedServiceBean.java:108)
        at arch.service.beans.RepBasedServiceImpl.onMessage(RepBasedServiceImpl.java:202)
        at arch.service.beans.RepBasedServiceImpl.message(RepBasedServiceImpl.java:229)
        at arch.CORBA.service.ServicePOA.local_message(ServicePOA.java:188)
        at arch.CORBA.Transport.sendLocalRequest(Transport.java:447)
        at arch.transport.StubProxy.send_managed_request(StubProxy.java:364)
        at arch.transport.StubProxy.invoke(StubProxy.java:205)
        at $Proxy15.start(Unknown Source)
        at arch.service.beans.RepositoryBasedServiceFactory.startDeployable(RepositoryBasedServiceFactory.java:423)
        at arch.service.beans.ServiceContainer$ServiceStarter.run(ServiceContainer.java:1392)
        at arch.service.beans.ServiceContainer$ThreadPool._run(ServiceContainer.java:2934)
        at arch.util.ThreadPool._runLoopBody(ThreadPool.java:213)
        at arch.util.ThreadPool._runForThread(ThreadPool.java:230)
        at arch.util.ThreadPool.access$000(ThreadPool.java:3)
        at arch.util.ThreadPool$1.run(ThreadPool.java:95)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AUTHav.class` is corrupt (sometimes?). Obviously some method is declared to throw something that is not a subclass of Throwable. Usually this shouldn't happen because a Java compiler would detect that problem and report an error. But maybe the class file is modified/instrumented or even generated at runtime and this introduces the sporadic error. Or you have a naming conflict and the classloaded sporadically sees a diffenent, non-Throwable class instead of the intended one.

If `AUTHav.class` is contained in some archive, you could have a look at the byte code (with `javap` or a decompiler) and check if you find a method with a suspicious `throws` argument.

---

So the byte code is obfuscated ... then it could be - and this is just a guess - that you have more than one version of the library inside your J2EE container. As the classes are obfuscated, there is a chance that the class names `AUTHa7` and/or `AUTHa1` are used for different (orginal) classes in different versions of the library. And then, if the classloader picks up both or maybe the wrong one at the wrong time, it could happen, that `AUTHa7` and/or `AUTHa1` are not Exceptions at runtime...

Comment: I Checked the byte code of  AUTHav.class . There is one method as below ,

public synchronized void a(AUTHa0 autha0) throws AUTHa7, AUTHa1

here ,  the  AUTHa7  extends AUTHa1 and the AUTHa1 extends the 'Exception'  class....so I feel nothing is suspicious here...do you have any idea ..?

Comment: thanks Andreas , I checked my classpath , there are two class files with the same name from different JAR files . one of those two extends " Exception "  that is the intended one , and the other one doent. Thank you.

Comment: ... unbelievable - it really was just are very wild guess. Glad to hear that it was a hit :-)

Answer (score 1):

My guess: faulty hardware, especially RAM, causing the JVM to get corrupt bytecode. Usually it causes outright JVM crashes, but it's certainly a possibility worth checking out:

[Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)